# Convert GPS for NOAA national snowfall analysis

Tags: python, noaa, lambert-conformal-conic

I'd like to get snow accumulation data for specific GPS coordinates (hiking peaks in the south east) using netCDF4 data from NOAA's snowfall analysis available [here](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/snowfall/).

According to the metadata (at the very bottom of post), the data uses a Lambert Conformal Conic 1SP projection (which is ESPG 9801 from what I've read). However, this CRS doesn't seem to be supported by Python. Additionally, while y/x seem to be the Lambert projection, I can't make sense of the lat/lon values in the data. The lat ranges from ~20 to ~52 and the lon from ~230 to ~299. Should I use the y/x or lat/lon, and how could I make the conversion from GPS?

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
import pyproj

fn = '/sfav2_CONUS_72h_2024012912_grid184.nc'
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(fn, mode="r")

# Look at data
plt.contourf(nc['Data'][:,:])
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

```
# Convert GPS to Lambert conformal conic projection
gps_coords = (-83.436715, 35.65435) # Mount LeConte
target_crs = 'epsg:9801'
source_crs = 'epsg:4326'

to_lambert = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(source_crs, target_crs)
coord_x, coord_y = to_lambert.transform(gps_coords[0], gps_coords[1])

CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:9801: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)

(np.min(nc['lon']), np.max(nc['lon']))
Out[]: (229.89661431820417, 299.11409209512004)

(np.min(nc['lat']), np.max(nc['lat']))
Out[]: (20.191999999999986, 52.807544344820116)

(np.min(nc['x']), np.max(nc['x']))
Out[]: (-2763216.9521579794, 2681906.2798420205)

(np.min(nc['y']), np.max(nc['y']))
Out[]: (-263790.580335455, 3230840.7476645447)

nc['Lambert_conformal_conic']
Out[263]: 
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
|S1 Lambert_conformal_conic()
    grid_mapping_name: lambert_conformal_conic
    standard_parallel: 25.0
    longitude_of_central_meridian: 265.0
    latitude_of_projection_origin: 25.0
    false_easting: 0.0
    false_northing: 0.0
    semi_major_axis: 6371229.0
    inverse_flattening: 0.0
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = ()
filling on, default _FillValue of used
```

Comment: I think you just need to define LLC https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438679/276 >"+proj=lcc +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-100 +lat_1=25 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" #my custom CRS

Comment: Thanks! Tho not sure that's exactly it - I'm looking for Lambert conformal conic 1SP, there're a couple I think. I tested that custom CRS at a place where there should be snow but got none. Is there documentation for creating a custom CRS, the link in that post seems to be no longer working?